# Programatically make changes to Zune tracks

Tags: c#, api, dll, zune

Does anyone know of any APIs available for Microsoft's Zune application? I want to modify the ratings of the songs that are loaded in Zune without having to open the Zune app. There is a ZuneStore.sdf database sitting in my AppData folder, but I cannot open it in Microsoft SQL Management Studio as it looks to be a special format. Surely there must be some way to modify this data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the closet I have found to an API. It controls the Zune player. Going to see what I can do with this.

http://zunelcd.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlce/thread/6bd9a2f2-48b0-4fb0-a84b-1e76c36113dc

> I can open the Zune database in SSMS 2008, but it is not in a standard SQL Compact format, so cannot run any queries against it. Consider it to be in a proprietary, undocumented, protected format.

So I guess not.

Comment: This is so annoying as Microsoft is normally good to at least provide some rudimentary form of API or access.